# StreamBuilder not updating after an item is removed Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, stream-builder

I am new to Flutter and this is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow. I apologize for any misunderstanding. I will try my best to make it clear.

I am using sqflite for storing user's favorites and populating a list from the DB on a page, named Favorites screen. This Favorites page is one of the items on my bottom navbar.

My issue is that when I tap on an item from the favorites list which takes me to a screen where I can unfavorite that item. I double-checked that it is really removed from the DB by logging the rows count. But when I go back to the Favorites page, that item is still on the list. If I go to one of the pages from the bottom navbar and go back to the Favorites screen, the item isn't there. I understand that the page is being rebuilt again this time but my intention was the Stream will constantly listen for a change.

I have also implemented a slide to dismiss feature on the fav screen, which works as intended. But I am using the same logic on both.

**StreamBuilder code in Favorite screen**

```
 StreamBuilder<List<WeekMezmurList>>(
     stream: favBloc.favStream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<WeekMezmurList>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              "Loading Favorites...",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              "No Favorites yet!",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            AudioPlayerScreen(
                              mezmurName: snapshot.data[index].mezmurName,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                child: Slidable(
                  key: new Key(snapshot.data[index].mezmurName),
                  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                  // closes other active slidable if there is any
                  controller: slidableController,
                  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                    IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Share',
                      color: Colors.indigo,
                      icon: Icons.share,
                      onTap: () =>
                          _share(snapshot
                              .data[index]),
                    ),
                    IconSlideAction(
                      caption: 'Delete',
                      color: Colors.red,
                      icon: Icons.delete,
                      onTap: () =>
                          _swipeDelete(
                              context, snapshot.data[index].mezmurName),
                    ),
                  ],
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(                  
                        vertical: 15.0,
                        horizontal: 10.0,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              _misbakChapter(
                                  snapshot.data[index].misbakChapters),
                              SizedBox(width: 15),
                              _displayFavoritesMisbakLines(
                                  snapshot.data[index], index),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

**slide to delete code in Favorites screen**

```
  // deletes the specific favorite from the sqflite db
  Future<void> _swipeDelete(BuildContext context, String mezmurName) async {
    try {
      favBloc.delete(mezmurName);
    } catch (e) {
      CupertinoAlertDialog(
        content: Text("Something went wrong. Please try again."),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text(
              "Ok",
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

I have the same logic in the second screen, the screen I get when I tap on one of the items from the Fav list.

```
favBloc.delete(widget.mezmurName);
```

**BLoC code**, I got the concepts from this [Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b)

```
class FavoritesBloc{
  FavoritesBloc(){
    getFavorites();
  }

  final databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  // broadcast makes it to start listening to events
  final _controller = StreamController<List<WeekMezmurList>>.broadcast();
  get favStream => _controller.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }

  getFavorites () async{
    _controller.sink.add(await databaseHelper.getFavorites());
  }

  insert(WeekMezmurList fav){
    databaseHelper.insertToDb(fav);
    getFavorites();
  }

  delete(String mezmurName){
    databaseHelper.delete(mezmurName: mezmurName);
    getFavorites();
  }
}
```

**Delete method in the DB class**

```
 // deleting a value from the db
   delete({String mezmurName}) async {
    var dbClient = await getDb;
    try {
      await dbClient
          .delete(TABLE, where: '$MEZMUR_NAME = ?', whereArgs: [mezmurName]);
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
```

I have tried to research this issue but all I have found were for remote databases.

Just to make it more clear, I took a [screen record.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XPQqrtjK9pT-7Dcyjt2iydgEinClagrn/view)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you said you unfavorite that item in the second screen and when returning your item is still in favorite, do you use the same instance of FavoritesBloc? if the second screen use the delete method that doesnt mean it will update the Stream of the first if they're not related (not same instance), where or how do you create FavoritesBloc in each screen? initState of an statefulWidget in each screen?

Comment: Use await for `databaseHelper.delete(mezmurName: mezmurName);`

Comment: @EdwynZN Thanks for your reply. If I got your question right, I am just declaring the instances like ```final favBloc = FavoritesBloc();``` in both screens outside of initState. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @SanjaySharma Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it is still the same

Comment: No, it's ok the way you do it, but that just means each screen has a different instance of FavoritesBlock, so when you un favorite it in the second screen it updates the stream on that instance, but that won't affect the first page because they're different instances (each one with its proper stream). When using material route to open the second screen, try sending favoriteBlock as an argument to the second page

Comment: @EdwynZN Thanks a lot! Your suggestion has solved my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped, just remember know you're using the same object in both routes, so when using pop from the second route don't dispose FavoritesBloc because you're still using it in the first route, dispose it when you're sure you're not using it anymore

Comment: @EdwynZN Thanks, will make sure to do that. For some reason, I don't have the accept or upvote an answer features. But, I consider it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why StreamBuilder on the first screen doesn't update with the changes made is because it uses a different instance of `FavoritesBloc()`. If you'd like for the bloc to be globally accessible with a single instance, you can declare it as

```dart
final favBloc = FavoritesBloc();
```

Otherwise, you can follow what has been suggested in the comments and pass `FavoritesBloc` as an argument between screens.